Is there a way to apply branch policy coverage status checks to draft / unpublished pull requests in Azure DevOps?
I have a branch policy set on my main branch so that if anyone creates a pull request targeted to merge into that branch, the policy gets applied. The status check runs as expected if the pull request is published, but if the pull request remains as a draft / unpublished, then the status check won't run. Is there a way to make this status check run on draft pull requests?
According to the docs:

Draft pull requests do not include reviewers or run builds by default
but allow you to manually add reviewers and run builds. To promote the
pull request to a normal pull request, simply click the Publish button
from the pull request detail page.

This seems to imply that this is the intended default behavior, but also that there should be a way to override this behavior. Is this the case and if so, how can I apply this status check to any draft pull requests?
Below is some information on how this status check is specified currently:



As mentioned in the doc,

Draft pull requests do not include reviewers or run builds by default but allow you to manually add reviewers and run builds.

For a draft PR, you can click Queue to run the build manually.

Click View 2 checks, then you can see the status check.

If you would like to change the default settings of the code coverage experience for pull requests, you can include a configuration YAML file named azurepipelines-coverage.yml at the root of your repo. For example,
coverage:
  status:           # Code coverage status will be posted to pull requests based on targets defined below.
    comments: on    # Off by default. When on, details about coverage for each file changed will be posted as a pull request comment. 
    diff:           # Diff coverage is code coverage only for the lines changed in a pull request.
      target: 60%   # Set this to a desired percentage. Default is 70 percent

Then you can see the code coverage details in the PR comment. See the detailed info from Code coverage for pull requests.


Much appreciated. It sounds like there's no way to automatically queue these up for draft PRs then, is that correct?

You are right, there isn't such default feature. According to this doc PR triggers, draft pull requests do not trigger a pipeline even if you configure a branch policy.
